# Spring Security unable to create JSESSION id with Nginx Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nginx, spring-security

I have implemented the spring security with in spring mvc application and it is working fine for me But I am try to access this application with Nginx server configuration now Spring Security stop working at Last I have found that spring security is unable to create JSESSIONID cookies with Nginx server.

Can any one help me Please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have got way how to handle Cookies in Ngnix Server.

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/Url/;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_cookie_domain localhost test.com;
        proxy_cookie_path /Url/ /;
    }
```